# How to set up vue-advanced-chat?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to install https://github.com/antoine92190/vue-advanced-chat#installation according to the instructions - as a result, when I try to use the component, I get an error even in the simplest test case:

```
error  in ./node_modules/vue-advanced-chat/dist/vue-advanced-chat.common.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (17025:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|           emoji,
|           skinTone: currentSkinTone,
|           ...skinTonedUnicode && { unicode: skinTonedUnicode },
|           ...emojiSummary.name && { name: emojiSummary.name }
|       });

 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue 10:0-43
 @ ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8082 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Perhaps the problem is in the versions of my packages, but I could not catch what exactly, here is what is installed:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vue2-adv-chat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "Алексей С <whthaker@gmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-advanced-chat": "^1.5.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation stands that the minimal version of Vue is 2.6.14. Check your version and update if it's smaller.

Comment: Oh god, I'm so inconsiderate. Tried diligently choosing VUE up to version 2.6.14 and it turned out that it works even with VUE 3 if you use the "next" branch